# how can i make this papervision3d code work?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5, papervision3d

This code works but it does display the cube as the first code and the view, zoom and interactivity is different, so i wanted the cube to be displayed as in the first code with the same features.

first code is here: http://papervision2.com/10-advanced-interactivity/

```
  package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import org.papervision3d.materials.ColorMaterial;
    import org.papervision3d.materials.MovieMaterial;
    import org.papervision3d.materials.utils.MaterialsList;
    import org.papervision3d.objects.primitives.Cube;
    import org.papervision3d.view.BasicView;

    public class Main extends BasicView 
    {
        protected var cube:Cube;
        protected var interactiveMats:Array;
        protected var materialsList:MaterialsList;
        protected var targetrotationX:Number;
        protected var targetrotationY:Number;
        protected var targetrotationZ:Number;
        protected var tweening:Boolean;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            super();
            init();
        }
        protected function init():void 
        {
            createChildren();
            startRendering();
        }
        protected function createChildren():void 
        {
            //Set the viewport to interactive
            viewport.interactive = true;

            //Create Materials:
            materialsList           = new MaterialsList();
            interactiveMats         = ["front", "back", "left", "right", "bottom", "top"];
            var colorsArray:Array   = [0x76b6f8, 0x4291e1, 0x1f73c8, 0xe77111, 0xe8914c, 0xfad2b2];

            for (var i:int = 0; i < interactiveMats.length; i++)
            {
                //Create a color box so we can use our MouseEvents
                var colorBox:Sprite = new Sprite();
                colorBox.graphics.beginFill(colorsArray[i]);
                colorBox.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
                colorBox.graphics.endFill();
                colorBox.name = interactiveMats[i];

                //Add a textField for reference
                var textField:TextField = new TextField()
                colorBox.addChild(textField)
                textField.text = interactiveMats[i];

                //Add a MouseEvent to the Sprite
                colorBox.mouseChildren = false;
                colorBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMovieMatClicked);

                //Create the MovieMat
                var movieMat:MovieMaterial      = new MovieMaterial(colorBox, true, true);
                movieMat.interactive            = true;
                movieMat.smooth                 = true;
                materialsList.addMaterial(movieMat, interactiveMats[i]);
            }

            //Create Cube
            cube    = new Cube(materialsList, 100, 100, 100);

            //Add cube to the scene
            scene.addChild(cube);
        }

        protected function onMovieMatClicked(evt:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            if (tweening) 
            {
                // Let it rotate again
                tweening = false;
            }
            else 
            {
                switch(evt.target.name) {
                    case "front":
                        targetrotationX = 0;
                        targetrotationY = 180;
                        targetrotationZ = 0;
                        tweening = true;
                    break;
                    case "back":
                        targetrotationX = 0;
                        targetrotationY = 0;
                        targetrotationZ = 0;
                        tweening = true;
                    break;
                    case "left":
                        targetrotationX = 0;
                        targetrotationY = -90;
                        targetrotationZ = 0;
                        tweening = true;
                    break;
                    case "right":
                        targetrotationX = 0;
                        targetrotationY = 90;
                        targetrotationZ = 0;
                        tweening = true;
                    break;
                    case "top":
                        targetrotationX = -90;
                        targetrotationY = 0;
                        targetrotationZ = 0;
                        tweening = true;
                    break;
                    case "bottom":
                        targetrotationX = 90;
                        targetrotationY = 0;
                        targetrotationZ = 180;
                        tweening = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        override protected function onRenderTick(event:Event = null):void 
        {
            super.onRenderTick(event);

            if (tweening) {
                // If a face has been clicked
                if (camera.zoom <230) {
                    // If the camera isn't zoomed enough then zoom in a bit more:
                    camera.zoom += Math.sqrt(230-camera.zoom)/5;
                }
                // Test each rotation and rotate it towards the target rotation:
                // X axis:
                if (cube.rotationX < targetrotationX) 
                {
                    cube.rotationX += Math.sqrt(targetrotationX-cube.rotationX);
                    cube.rotationX = Math.round(cube.rotationX);
                }
                else if (cube.rotationX > targetrotationX) 
                {
                    cube.rotationX -= Math.sqrt(cube.rotationX-targetrotationX);
                    cube.rotationX = Math.round(cube.rotationX);
                }

                // Y axis:
                if (cube.rotationY < targetrotationY) 
                {
                    cube.rotationY += Math.sqrt(targetrotationY-cube.rotationY);
                    cube.rotationY = Math.round(cube.rotationY);
                }
                else if (cube.rotationY > targetrotationY) 
                {
                    cube.rotationY -= Math.sqrt(cube.rotationY-targetrotationY);
                    cube.rotationY = Math.round(cube.rotationY);
                }

                // Z axis:
                if (cube.rotationZ < targetrotationZ) 
                {
                    cube.rotationZ += Math.sqrt(targetrotationZ-cube.rotationZ);
                    cube.rotationZ = Math.round(cube.rotationZ);
                }
                else if (cube.rotationZ > targetrotationZ) 
                {
                    cube.rotationZ -= Math.sqrt(cube.rotationZ-targetrotationZ);
                    cube.rotationZ = Math.round(cube.rotationZ);
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                // If the camera is zoomed in, it shouldn't be now
                if (camera.zoom > 200) 
                {
                    // So zoom out a bit.
                    camera.zoom -= Math.sqrt(camera.zoom-2)/5;
                }
                // Rotate the cube a bit:
                cube.rotationX += 2;
                cube.rotationY += 2;
                // Make sure that we dont "wind up" the rotation
                if (cube.rotationX>= 360) cube.rotationX = 0;
                if (cube.rotationY>= 360) cube.rotationY = 0;
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

code2 taken from: http://papervision2.com/advanced-interactivity/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However the article was submitted, it parsed `<` to `&lt;` and `>` to `&gt;`.

Do a find/replace for each of those and the bulk of the errors should go away.

Comment: hey matt done that but it didnt work but ive check upon something there is a new version to the code which has been updated and the changes you have said have been made in the code already and that code does work, but the problem is i dont want the cube to have that type of interactivity i want it to do what it does in the 1st code, so is it possible if we can change the code around ive tried it but it didnt work much as im not an expert and as3 but yeah most of the code is the same but updated, its defining the cube and its paramiters and materials to make it working,will add updated code

Comment: I don't really have any real experience with Papervision 3D. I've edited your question to aid your search further seeing as the previous problem was fixed.